# Setting GitLab environmental variable via a bash command

Tags: bash, gitlab

So. I'm using GitLab and in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have the following:

```
variables:
    CONTAINER_NAME: $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME | tr / -
```

The `$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` basically reads the branch name, in my case `development/karl`. I'm trying to set the variable name `CONTAINER_NAME` to `development-karl` though.

It doesn't seem to be working as when I echo the variable, the following shows:

```
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
development/karl | tr / -
```

I was expecting:

```
$ echo $CONTAINER_NAME
development-karl
```

Comment: Just stumbled over the same thing. Did you happen to solve it? Feel free to answer your own question :)